# ErrorDocument disbales .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, errordocument

If i add `ErrorDocument` directive to the `.htaccess` file , everything stops working . Do now know where is my mistake. Then i remove `ErrorDocument` directive, everything again works.

I have tried to use path relative to document root, or full url.
I also tried to make a separate folder in document root `/err/errMsg.php` and refer to it  `ErrorDocument 100 http://localhost/domainname.biz/err/errMsg.php` , nevertheless, it would be better to be redirected to`public/index.php/err/err action`.

My document root is :

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/name/public_html/domainname.biz  on server 
DOCUMENT_ROOT   ...../apache2/htdocs    on localhost
```

`.htaccess` file  for `localhost` :

```
ErrorDocument 100  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
#i also used ErrorDocument 100 http://localhost/domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 101  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 102  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 200  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 201  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 202  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 203  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 204  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 205  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 206  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 207  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 226  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 300  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 301  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 302  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 303  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 304  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 305  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 306  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 307  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 400  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 401  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 402  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 403  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 404  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 405  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 406  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 407  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 408  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 409  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 410  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 411  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 412  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 413  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 414  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 415  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 416  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 417  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 422  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 423  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 424  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 426  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 500  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 501  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 502  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 503  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 504  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 505  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 506  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 507  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
ErrorDocument 510  /domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err

Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymlinks
# +FollowSymLinks must be enabled for any rules to work, this is a security requirement of the rewrite engine. 
# Normally it's enabled in the root and you shouldn't have to add it, but it doesn't hurt to do so, 
# Although highly unlikely, your host may have +FollowSymLinks enabled at the root level, 
# yet disallow its addition in .htaccess; in which case, adding +FollowSymLinks will break your setup
#  (probably a 500 error), so just remove it, and your rules should work fine.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
IndexIgnore *  


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.biz [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname\.biz [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}



RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^index.php?(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`.htaccess` file on server is the same, but i start from another document root

```
ErrorDocument 100  /public/index.php/err/err
#or https://www.domainname.biz/public/index.php/err/err
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why do you have so many `ErrorDocument` lines in your .htaccess:

At the minimum remove the line for unsupported response code `306` to avoid 500 internal error on your website.

You should also remove handled for response code `200` as that is good status.

Comment: Thank you. Seems 306 was the reason. I took these codes from http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument/
and  http://www.askapache.com/php/php-errordocument/   I left 200, because i wanted to check if works.

Comment: I am sorry, it works only on localhost, not on remote server.

Comment: i am getting the page: 500 Internal error occurred. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: On my Apache only `306` was giving 500 internal server error. You will need to check error.log on remote server to know the cause of this error.

Comment: - [05/Apr/2017:00:08:41 -0700] "GET /public/index.php/security/login HTTP/1.1" 200 6349 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"

Comment: I can see only error 200. Vierd. give me more time to understand WHY. If i remove `ErrorDocument` directives, i do not encounter errors - everything is working. Now i have changed, i left only 400 and 500 codes.

Comment: The error log does not make sense, because it shows url, which i was not visiting at all : i posted it to the question

Comment: You don't need to give full file system path. Just try `DrrorXocument 404 /index.php/err`